# Redirecionar usuario logeado a ruta según rol

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Estoy modificando un proyecto desarrollado con Laravel 8 y Jeatstream. Estoy intentando de redigir a los usuarios a diferentes rutas según el rol (spatie) que tienen asignado una vez se han logado.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que una vez logeo al usuario con rol de administrador y cierro sesión, si intento posteriormente acceder con un usuario con rol de participante este es dirigido a la ruta visitada con el usuario anterior y me indica que no tengo el acceso permitido debido al rol.

Estas son las rutas que tengo creadas, cada una con su controlador asociado:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get(
'/dashboard', [DashController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get(
'/dashboardstudent', [DashstudentController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.student.dashboard');
```

Para comprobar el rol asignado a cada usuario y hacer la redirección he modificado el Middleware **RedirectIfAuthenticated** haciendo la siguiente modificación.

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated {
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  ...$guards
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrador')) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }

            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Supervisor')) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            
            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Participante')) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.student.dashboard');
            }                
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

}

No sé si el procedimiento que estoy utilizando es el más optimo para redirigir a un usuario a una ruta concreta según el rol que tiene asignado.

Os agradecería cualquier ayuda que me podáis dar para solucionar el problema.

Un saludo.

Comment: Me podría indicar alguien si la lógica aplicada para la redirección del usuario una vez logado según su rol es correcta o por el contrario podría hacerlo de otra forma más optima.

Comment: Buenos días. Nadie me puede orientar....